# sql output json structure

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I need to get the following output about the sql query:

```json
{
    "records": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "customer"
            },
            "name": "test 1",
            "email": "test1@test.com"
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "customer"
            },
            "name": "test 2",
            "email": "test2@test2.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

my attempt:

```sql
DECLARE @ttCustomer table (cname nvarchar(50),
                           email nvarchar(250));
INSERT @ttCustomer
VALUES ('test 1', 'test1@test.com');
INSERT @ttCustomer
VALUES ('test 2', 'test2@test.com');
SELECT 'customer' AS [records.attributes.type],
       cname AS [records.name],
       email AS [records.email]
FROM @ttCustomer
FOR JSON PATH;
```

almost perfect output result

```json
[
    {
        "records": {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "customer"
            },
            "name": "test 1",
            "email": "test1@test.com"
        }
    },
    {
        "records": {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "customer"
            },
            "name": "test 2",
            "email": "test2@test.com"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define your `ROOT`:

```sql
DECLARE @ttCustomer table (cname nvarchar(50),
                           email nvarchar(250));
INSERT @ttCustomer
VALUES ('test 1', 'test1@test.com');
INSERT @ttCustomer
VALUES ('test 2', 'test2@test.com');
SELECT 'customer' AS [attributes.type],
       cname AS [name],
       email AS [email]
FROM @ttCustomer
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('records');
```

Outputs:

```json
{
    "records": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "customer"
            },
            "name": "test 1",
            "email": "test1@test.com"
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "customer"
            },
            "name": "test 2",
            "email": "test2@test.com"
        }
    ]
}
```